# Crystal Field Splitting Energy and Metal Energy Level

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

Second and third row metals are stated to often have higher crystal field splitting energies than first row metals. The argument is usually made that the more diffuse 4d and 5d orbitals are capable of better overlap and decreased pairing energy. However, two concepts do not make sense to me:

1. Why do more diffuse orbitals lead to better sigma overlap? In organic chemistry it is often taught that size mismatch between orbitals contributes to poorer overlap, not better.
2. A 4d orbital will be higher in energy than the 3d orbital in the same group. From an MO theory perspective, I would expect this to mean that the energy difference between the ligand group orbitals and metal d orbitals increases and results in less splitting.